# How to Run Code on Android Generated by AndoirdViewClient?

Tags: android, python, adb, androidviewclient

Through the CulebraTester application on my device, I generated some python to simply open the settings application. When I went to run the script, I was greeted with

> pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'androidviewclient<12.4.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application

So then I realized that I didn't have the environment variable set, so I downloaded the project from Github and ran the command

> export ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME=/path/to/androidviewclient/

I'm confident I did this correctly because I can cd to $ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME and view the contents. Now when I go back to run the script this same error appears, so I commented out pkg_resources.require('androidviewclient>=12.4.0') and was then presented with this error

> ImportError: No module named com.dtmilano.android.viewclient

Right now I'm clueless about what to do, I tried googling, but I've found nothing to fix the problem. Some-what related I saw a video on youtube where curl was used to run javascript generated by CulebraTester so maybe the same can be done with Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[CulebraTester](http://culebra.dtmilano.com/)** can generate tests in a variety of languages:

- Python
- Java
- Kotlin
- Javascript
- etc.

see [Code-Generation-language](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester-public/wiki/Code-Generation-language) for details.

Each language has its own dependencies in order to run, for example, if you generate **UiAutomator** tests in **Java** you will need the corresponding dependencies in your `build.gradle`.

In your specific case, as you have generated Python tests you need `androidviewclient`. To install it, follow the instructions on [AndroidViewClient: Installation](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki#installation)

Comment: Hey Diego I do have androidviewclient, I followed your wiki for installing it and as you see above set the environment variable for ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME. I don't understand what I'm missing, why can't I compile the python script CulebraTester generated? What will fix the error: "ImportError: No module named com.dtmilano.android.viewclient"? Thanks.

Comment: Did you install with `easy_install`?

Comment: Are you using Linux?

Comment: I'm on a Mac. I used easy_install and to check I ran "sudo easy_install --upgrade androidviewclient," and it said, "androidviewclient 13.5.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth." I ran the check-import.py in your examples and received an "OK" and that's weird because line 35-39 are importing the things that are giving me an error in my generated python file. I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I found the issue; I was running the python script through Sublime Text. If I run the command "python2 /path/to/file.py" the script works as expected, sorry for wasting time on this silly mistake. I assume Sublime Text was defaulting to python3.